# Strong Diffie-Hellman Problem

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, hardness-assumptions

While reading the following [paper](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2006/40040001/40040001.pdf) about the Strong Diffie-Hellman Problem, i got curious about ways to compute $ g^{x^{l}} $ for unknown  $x$ in an elliptic curve, without first solving the discrete logarithm problem for $g^x$. Since SDH may not be as hard as DL, there might be a way to get $g^{x^{l}}$ without knowing $x$ first. I couldn't find anything that tires to solve SDH for specific finite groups and would welcome if someone could point me in the direction of related work or has an idea how this could be done.